# JavaScript on Visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, npm

PS C:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022> node "c:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mycode\second.js"
node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- node "c:\Users\Admin\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\mycode\sec ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (node:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: You need to add node.js to your environment variables. Open `Evironment variables` (I'm assuming you know where they are), choose `path` in the `System variables` section and click `edit`. In the new window, click on `New` and add your node.js installation folder, then apply all the changes and try again.

Comment: Is the node.js need to be in same path of visual studio code

Comment: It's the directory where you installed node.js

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to install a node in your system.
Follow this guide for the same. https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Ensure you are on the proper path while accessing the terminal after installing the node and starting your project.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i have installed it as default path